# Cmake for Building Blocks (folder include of source)

Tags: c++, architecture, cmake, directory

We are retroactively adding a building block superstructure to our code base. This means new namespace rules (cpp) and a new folder structure.

My question concerns changes to our make file environment (Cmake) and a how we should approach this change(we are utterly confused).

**Our goal:**

1. one "global" CMakeLists.txt file that adds blocks in a *feature like
   way* to our build.
2. each block build artifacts (*.h, *.cpp ...)should be defined in a sub CMakeLists.txt file **inside** each new
   block.

**Overview:**

Is:

```
  +-src
  +--block1.cpp
  +--block1_1.cpp
  +--block(n+1).cpp
  +--CMakeLists.txt  <- old global make file
  +-include
  +--block1.h
  +--block1_1.h
  +--block(n+1).h
```

Should:

```
  - Block 1
  +- src
  +-- block1.cpp
  +-- block1_1.cpp
  +- inlcude
  +-- block1.h
  +-- block1_1.h
  **+- CMakeLists.txt** <- sub list file that handles target req. of Block 1
  + Block 2
  +- ... (same structure as 1)
  + Block 3
  +- ... (same structure as 1)
  +-CMakeLists.txt <- global list file that adds Blocks to target
```

We do not want to add block build artifacts information to our global list file (like add aux_source_directory, include_directories). The reason: There are *too many* blocks for this approach and we want to configure build with different blocks.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure to understand your question; you want to have a different build configuration for each block? Which means the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` cannot drive the whole project with calls to `add_subdirectory()`?

Comment: yes? this sums up what i want to do. Or do i miss something?

Comment: What is your actual question? This is straightforward to implement using standard modern CMake since each CMakeLists.txt has its own sub-scope. The blocks don't need to know anything about each other except as targets. Just use the `target_*` commands for as much as possible.

Comment: @utopia I agree with you that using `target_*` commands prevents this problem, but this may not be that simple; for example if cache variables are altered by a sub-directory it may impact the other directories.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CMake module [`ExternalProject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) to drive the compilation of projects that are independent from each other. You could have a top-level `CMakeLists.txt` that contains for example:

```
include(ExternalProject)

externalproject_add(block1 URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/block1)
externalproject_add(block2 URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/block2)
```

Then, you create a build directory which you configure with this top-level `CMakeLists.txt`; it will have two targets `block1` and `block2`, where each target will build the corresponding project independently.